# How to write superscripts and subscripts in math mode?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

[image]

I just started using latex and the closest I've come is

```
$F\overset{fr}{\textsubscript{s}max}$
```

or

```
$F{fr \above 0pt \ \textsubscript{s}max}$
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this one:

```
$F^{\mathrm{fr}}_{s\mathrm{MAX}}$.
```

In math mode `^` means superscript and `_` means subscript.

[image]